# NoClassDeffFound error with gradle while trying to use api wrapper

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, bukkit

Can someone please help me out.

I am getting a NoClassDeffFound error and I do not know why.

I am trying to code minecraft plugin for a friends guild and I am getting an error when trying to get info about the player.

I am using this api wrapper: https://github.com/KevinPriv/HypixelApi4J

This is my build.gradle:

```
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    maven { url = 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile "com.github.KevinPriv:HypixelApi4J:API-1.7"
}
```

and this is my main class:

```
    public void onEnable(){
        HypixelAPI hypixel = new HypixelAPI(KEY);
        String id = "";
        try {
            id = hypixel.getGuildID("Miqhtie");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (APIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Guild guild = null;
        try {
            guild = hypixel.getGuild(id);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (APIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Guild Name: " + guild.getName());
    }

}
```

and here is my stack trace:

````
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/kbrewster/exceptions/APIException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:139) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:394) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:301) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:377) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:186) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/kbrewster/exceptions/APIException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.kbrewster.exceptions.APIException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.16.1.jar:git-Spigot-758abbe-2b00831]
        ... 7 more```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shade the dependency into your jar with the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).